# Is this the right way to enable GPS programmatically through the use of android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS?

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-location

I'm developing an app whose permission includes `android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS` (to be granted through `adb`).

This is the code to automatically enable GPS

```
public static boolean forceGpsOn(Context context){
    if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        return false;
    }
    try {
        android.provider.Settings.Secure.putInt(context.getContentResolver(),
        android.provider.Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE,
        android.provider.Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    }
    catch (Exception _e){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

which works, but I am unsure wether it's the right way, 'cause `Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE` and `Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE_HIGH_ACCURACY` are both [deprecated](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure#LOCATION_MODE) but can't find a valid alternative.

Thank you.

Comment: Why would you need a permission to write? Using gps is reading only. And not from settings.

Comment: have a look at access fine location and acces .... location.

Comment: I'm sorry, but my goal is to enable GPS toggle programmatically. I know how to ask for permissions, but need the app to be able to toggle Location through code.